# Why doesn't my cloud function get updated when I redeploy through terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, terraform, google-cloud-functions

I had deployed some cloud functions on gcp through my terraform configuration using their respective zip files. I made changes to my functions,  new zips for that and redeployed them with new zips through the same terraform configuration. But successful deployment, my changes did not reflect in my cloud functions.

Here is my terraform code - `main.tf`:

```
# Creating a storage bucket to store cloud function objects
resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name     = "${var.project_id}-bucket1"
  location = var.region
}

data "archive_file" "function_src" {
  for_each    = var.functions
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "/tmp/${each.value.zip}"
  source_dir  = "../function-zips"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "function_zip" {
  for_each = var.functions
  name     = each.key
  bucket   = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source   = each.value.zip
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
  for_each = var.functions
  name     = each.value.name
  location = var.region

  build_config {
    runtime     = each.value.runtime
    entry_point = each.value.entrypoint

    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.function_zip[each.key].name
      }
    }
  }
  service_config {
    min_instance_count             = 1
    available_memory               = "128Mi"
    timeout_seconds                = 120
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision = false
    service_account_email          = "terraform-gcf@terraform-cloud-functions-ems.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "member" {
  for_each = var.functions

  location = google_cloudfunctions2_function.function[each.key].location
  service  = each.key
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member   = "allUsers"
}
```

`provider.tf`:

```
provider "google" {
  project     = var.project_id
  region      = var.region
  credentials = "../tf-key.json"
}
```

`variables.tf`:

```
variable "project_id" {
  default = "terraform-cloud-functions-ems"
}

variable "region" {
  default = "us-central1"
}

variable "functions" {
  type = map(object({
    zip        = string
    name       = string
    trigger    = string
    runtime    = string
    entrypoint = string
  }))

  default = {
    "createemployee" : {
      zip        = "../function-zips/create-employee.zip"
      name       = "createEmployee"
      trigger    = "http-trigger"
      runtime    = "go121"
      entrypoint = "CreateEmployee"
    },
    "deleteemployee" : {
      zip        = "../function-zips/delete-employee.zip"
      name       = "deleteEmployee"
      trigger    = "http-trigger"
      runtime    = "go121"
      entrypoint = "DeleteEmployee"
    },
    "searchemployee" : {
      zip        = "../function-zips/search-employee.zip"
      name       = "searchEmployee"
      trigger    = "http-trigger"
      runtime    = "go121"
      entrypoint = "SearchEmployees"
    },
    "getemployeebyid" : {
      zip        = "../function-zips/get-employee-by-id.zip"
      name       = "getEmployeeById"
      trigger    = "http-trigger"
      runtime    = "go121"
      entrypoint = "GetEmployee"
    },
    "getallemployees" : {
      zip        = "../function-zips/get-all-employees.zip"
      name       = "getAllEmployees"
      trigger    = "http-trigger"
      runtime    = "go121"
      entrypoint = "GetAllEmployees"
    },
    "updateemployee" : {
      zip        = "../function-zips/update-employee.zip"
      name       = "updateEmployee"
      trigger    = "http-trigger"
      runtime    = "go121"
      entrypoint = "UpdateEmployee"
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know why doesn't my change get reflected?

I have all appropriate permissions for my service account that I am using to create my resources.

I was trying to redeploy my cloud functions with their updated zip files and was expecting the changes to be reflected. But old source code was their in my functions source even after redeploying my cloud functions with terraform apply command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the provider resource `google_cloudfunctions2_function` actually supports the update of `storage_source` as the [resourceCloudfunctions2functionUpdate](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/7552ac22be8e30597bd2fd96e1305e1e66d7396c/google/services/cloudfunctions2/resource_cloudfunctions2_function.go#L737) function doesn't have such code.

In addition to it, neither the `source` nor `storage_source` blocks have `ForceNew` flag set to recreate the resource in the event of change. If it's supported by Google REST API specs you could open a feature request with Hashicorp Google provider.